# Bad request from rest api here maps

Tags: dotnet-httpclient, here-api, here-maps-rest

I am attempting to use the Here Maps REST api to get map tiles, but even when using the example given by them, I keep getting error 400 bad request. 
The specific example I am using in this test is https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/topics/example-normal-day-view.html
That example is just one of many, that I have tried by now, which all return bad request.

I am not at all used to using web api's like this, so I might be doing something silly, which is not obvious to me. I am, however, able to use the REST api from open weather maps, which, at least as far as I can see, is not much different, and there are no issues with that, using the same method as below.

Might anyone here have an idea as to what is wrong?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var YOUR_APP_ID = "MYACTUALID";
var YOUR_APP_CODE = "MY-ACTUAL_APP_CODE";

var query= $"https://2.base.maps.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/11/525/761/256/png8? app_id ={ YOUR_APP_ID} &app_code ={ YOUR_APP_CODE}";

var request = client.GetAsync(query).Result;
```

Comment: Your query variable doesn't seem right. Print your query variable and see if it forms the expected string. Check '' app_id ={ YOUR_APP_ID} &app_code ={ YOUR_APP_CODE}''. Remove spaces and to use another variable value it should be put outside quotes or within ${} depending on the code  language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the example and it works.

Make sure to remove the spaces that are around the query parameters in the url that you pasted, so the query string should be:

```
https://[...]/png8?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
```

instead of

```
https://[...]/png8? app_id ={ YOUR_APP_ID} &app_code ={ YOUR_APP_CODE}
```

Comment: Well, that was simple. I was not aware that spaces were bad, and technically they wrote spaces in the example.. ok, I am just making excuses now.
Thanks a lot for the quick help. Much appreciated!

Comment: No worries! This is because the examples are formatted for readability, it happens to me as well because I keep using a manual copy-paste instead of the "copy" action on the side.